# Bootstrap modal closes when link inside it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where the user can click a 'Find User' link and a bootstrap modal is opened showing a table with users.  The modal loads in the remote page using jquery load.

The table contains header links to sort user by name etc.  Whenever i click the sort links the modal closes and the parent page redirects to the link clicked.

What i want is for the page within the modal window to redirect, NOT the parent page.  This way the user can sort the grid to find the user they are looking for.

I know if i change the page in the modal to use pure javascript i can do it using ajax but i dont really want to go down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i want is for the page within the modal window to redirect, NOT the parent page.

A modal is not a page, so any redirect of the page will reset the modal.

The only way I can think of, if you don't want to use js and/or ajax, is to load the table in an *iframe*.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <iframe src="myDataTable.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

This way, you can choose to only reload *myDataTable.html* within the iframe, without disturbing the "parent" or modal.